Does hinge loss penalize misclassifications beyond margin less than logistic loss?
This is a MCQ question I found

The hinge loss used in SVMs generally gives
less weight than logistic regression to points that are misclassified
with a high probability or score.
⋆ SOLUTION: True


When I looked at the graph of Hinge Loss and Logistic Loss , I can clearly see for misclassified points beyond margin , the loss from Hinge is greater than that from Logistic . Then why the answer is True.
